# Java Modules automatic modules with same package

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I develop JavaFX app with Hibernate for database access, and was faced with a problem:
I have in my module-info.java, automatic module from:

```
requires org.hibernate.orm.core; ( org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.12.Final)
requires sqlite.dialect; (com.zsoltfabok:sqlite-dialect:1.0)
```

They both have the same package "org.hibernate.dialect", since it is prohibited, what I can do to resolve this issue? I certainly could change the project to not use modules, and package it with jpackage as regular fat jar. But I would like to proceed with modularized one.
Thanks.

Comment: how is this related to javafx?

Comment: you should prefer reporting it to the library owners and there must be a cleanup planned for them to support modules.

Comment: You could also put these jars on the classpath instead of the module path, so that they do not become automatic modules, and then remove the references to them from your module-info.java.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite-dialect` uses the same package as `hibernate-core` which is either a dirty (my opinion) workaround for accessing foreign package private members or completely unnecessary if no package private members are accessed (I haven't checked it). You could make a fork of `sql-dialect` an change the package name (e.g., `com.zsoltfabok.hibernate.dialect.sqllite`), try if it works and in case it does use the fork instead (and create a pull request to the original repository).